# How to calculate the mutual information between two outputs of Rayleigh fading channels

Tags: random-variables, information-theory, entropy

We have the two channels:
$$X_{a,i} = H_{i}s_{i} +N_{a,i} \\
X_{b,i} = H_{i}s_{i} +N_{b,i} $$

for $1 \leq i \leq n$, where $H_i$ denotes the i.i.d. channel coefficient and is a zero-mean complex Gaussian random variable with variance one, i.e., $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$. Notice that the same $H_i$ is used in the two channels.

$N_{a,i}$ and $N_{b,i} $ represent the noises at node A and node B, respectively, and are independent $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_a^2)$ and $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_b^2)$ random variables.

$s_i$ is the channel input. We consider that a constant $s_i$ here, i.e., $s_i=s$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, and the power constraint for the input is $|s|^2 = \textrm{P}$.

The question is how to calculate the mutual information $I(X_a; X_b)$ for the above scenario.

The answer of this question is given as
$$I(X_a; X_b) = \log(1+ \gamma_{eq}),$$
where $\gamma_{eq} = \left(\frac{1}{\gamma_a}+ \frac{1}{\gamma_b}+ \frac{1}{\gamma_a \cdot \gamma_b} \right)^{-1}$, $\gamma_a = \frac{\textrm{P}}{\sigma_a^2}$ and $\gamma_b = \frac{\textrm{P}}{\sigma_b^2}$.

Can anyone please tell me how to derive the above mutual information. I really appreaciate it.

Comment: I don't understand the notation, in particular : "$H_i$ denotes the i.i.d. channel coefficient". I find strange usual that the channel is a Gaussian, and that it multiplies the input. Is $i$ indexes a multidimensional signal, or is some kind of time?

Comment: I am sorry that the description is not clear enough. $i$ is time index and represents the coherence interval of the channel. $H_i$ is the channel fading gain. It means in the coherence interval $i$, the channel gain will be assumed as a fixed value, but it independently changes to another fixed value in the next coherence interval. In other words, the actual value of $H_i$ has no relation with that of $H_j$ for $i \neq j $.

I found in another paper a solution for this problem. This should be help.
$$I(X_a;X_b) = h(X_a) + h(X_b) - h(X_a,X_b)$$

Comment: @leonbloy I think $X_a \sim  \mathcal{CN}( 0,P+\sigma_a^2 )$, which means $X_a$ follows the complex normal distribution. But I am not sure.

Now my problem is how to calculate $h(X_a, X_b)$, the differential entropy of two complex random variables.
By the way, $h(\cdot)$ represents the operator of differential entropy. 
Thank you very much for your help.